# Is there a directive in Microsoft Solver Foundation Services to match Solver in Excel?

Tags: optimization, excel-2010, solver, linear-programming, ms-solver-foundation

I have an Excel workbook that is using the Solver add-in to maximize a set of equations with a square root in it (e.g. it's non-linear). I'm attempting to re-implement this in C# using Microsoft Solver Foundation.  I've tried a few different directives but have not been able to find a solver that reproduces the results i get in Excel.

I tried using Hybrid Local Search, but the results come out all wrong and the resulting maximization doesn't come close to excel.  If I use the Interior Point Method and remove the square root (from both excel and c#), I get pretty close to the excel optimization but this is of no use to me since I'm trying to match the excel model that includes the square root.

I think the problem with the Hybrid local search is that i'm not getting a global maximum.  I didn't find any other built in directives that would support NLP.

I think Excel Solver uses the GRG2 algorithm.  Is there any way that I can reproduce the algorithm used by Excel solver in MSF?

For reference, here's the QP example that came with MSF with the changes that I've made preceded by the comment '// #######':

```
public string Solve()
        {
            /***************************
            /*Construction of the model*
            /***************************/
            SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
            //For repeating the solution with other minimum returns
            context.ClearModel();

            //Create an empty model from context
            Model portfolio = context.CreateModel();

            //Create a string set with stock names
            Set setStocks = new Set(Domain.Any, "Stocks");

            /****Decisions*****/

            //Create decisions bound to the set. There will be as many decisions as there are values in the set
            Decision allocations = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "Allocations", setStocks);
            allocations.SetBinding(StocksHistory, "Allocation", "Stock");
            portfolio.AddDecision(allocations);

            /***Parameters***/

            //Create parameters bound to Covariant matrix
            Parameter pCovariants = new Parameter(Domain.Real, "Covariants", setStocks, setStocks);
            pCovariants.SetBinding(Covariants, "Variance", "StockI", "StockJ");

            //Create parameters bound to mean performance of the stocks over 12 month period
            Parameter pMeans = new Parameter(Domain.Real, "Means", setStocks);
            pMeans.SetBinding(StocksHistory, "Mean", "Stock");

            portfolio.AddParameters(pCovariants, pMeans);

            /***Constraints***/

            //Portion of a stock should be between 0 and 1
            portfolio.AddConstraint("portion", Model.ForEach(setStocks, stock => 0 <= allocations[stock] <= 1));

            //Sum of all allocations should be equal to unity
            portfolio.AddConstraint("SumPortions", Model.Sum(Model.ForEach(setStocks, stock => allocations[stock])) == 1);


            /***Goals***/

            portfolio.AddGoal("Variance", GoalKind.Maximize,
                // ####### Include a inner product of the means and weights  to form utility curve
                Model.Sum
                (
                    Model.ForEach
                        (
                            setStocks, x =>
                                        Model.Product(
                                            allocations[x],
                                            pMeans[x])
                        )
                )
                -
                // ####### Use square root of variance to get volatility instead.  This makes the problem non-linear
                Model.Sqrt(
                    Model.Sum
                    (
                        Model.ForEach
                        (
                            setStocks, stockI =>
                            Model.ForEach
                            (
                                setStocks, stockJ =>
                                Model.Product(pCovariants[stockI, stockJ], allocations[stockI], allocations[stockJ])
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
             );
            // ####### remove event handler        

            /*******************
            /*Solve the model  *
            /*******************/

            // ####### Use an NLP algorithm directive
            Solution solution = context.Solve(new HybridLocalSearchDirective());

            // ####### remove conditions on propagate
                context.PropagateDecisions();

            // ####### Remove save.  Can't save an NLP Model

            Report report = solution.GetReport();
            return report.ToString();
        }
```